# Scrapping en R con html_nodes no funciona usando xpath ni css selector. Tampoco selenium

Tags: html, r, scraping, rvest

estoy intentando scrapear una página con R usando html_nodes.

Necesito extraer el nombre y el precio, y con el nombre usando el css selector funciona perfecto, pero con el precio todo lo que pongo como argumento me devuelve character 0.

Probé usando una extensión para encontrar el css selector pero no funciona, también el xpath que me devuelve la extensión y el xpath completo que obtengo de inspeccionar en chrome pero no hay caso.

El código html de la página tiene esta forma:

```
<span _ngcontent-s-accommodations-c105="" class="main-value">43.582</span>
```

Y mi código en R se ve asi:

```
price_1 <- tryCatch(main_page %>%html_nodes(".main-value") %>% html_text(),error=function(e) NA)
```

Alguna idea de que puede estar pasando?

Edit:

[Link a la URL que intento scrapear](https://www.despegar.com.ar/accommodations/detail/242649/2022-09-21/2022-09-22/2?selected_room_pack=1978242249&searchId=03a4e0ab-01a3-4781-b45e-1f32ca9d94d9&throughResults=true)

También intenté usar selenium:

```
driver$navigate(entrada) 
p1 = driver$findElement("css", ".main-value")    
price_1 <-getElementText(p1)
```

Pero me devuelve

> NoSuchElementException  run errorDetails method

Comment: Sabes si ese fragmento del documento HTML se genera dinámicamente (on Javascript?)

Comment: No lo se (ni tengo muy claro como descubrirlo, estoy aprendiendo jaja). Entiendo que de ser el caso podría usar Selenium, pero son varios links y me saca potencia. Existe alguna otra alternativa?

Comment: SI haces curl o wget de la URL y revisas el HTML resultante, ves ese fragmento? Ahí sabes. Ya más allá, mi burdo R no me da pa sugerir :)

Comment: Comparte la url sino no hay forma de verificar mucho, lo que te dice alfabravo es importante, `rvest` trabaja sobre código estático, si la página se consolida dinámicamente del lado del navegador, vas a necesitar usar otros métodos de scrapping, léase `rselenium`